# reading and writing binary files

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a problem with binary files. I want to create a binary file in which there will be numbers of version and subversion of program. Then, from that file I want to read what is inside by reading first sizeof(uint16_t) bites and then again sizeof(uint16_t) bites. But I don't know how to do that. (I'm not even close)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

void   saving_uint16_t(uint16_t number);
uint16_t reading_uint16_t();

int where = 0;

int main() {

    const uint16_t number_version = 2;
    cout << "Version: " << number_version << endl;
    cout << "Saving number..." << endl;
    saving_uint16_t(number_version);

    const uint16_t number_subversion = 1;
    cout << "Subversion: " << number_subversion << endl;
    cout << "Saving number..." << endl;
    saving_uint16_t(number_subversion);

    cout << "Read numbers:\nVersion: " << reading_uint16_t() << "\nSubversion: " << reading_uint16_t() << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

void saving_uint16_t(uint16_t number) {

    ofstream data("numbers.bin",  ios::app | ios::binary);
    data.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number), sizeof(uint16_t));
}

uint16_t reading_uint16_t(){

    ifstream data("numbers.bin", ios::binary);
    data.seekg(where);
    where = where + 16;
    uint16_t result;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result), sizeof(uint16_t));
    return result;
}
```

I'm really new with that and I don't know what to use.

Output:

```
Version: 3
Saving number...
Subversion: 7
Saving number...
Read numbers:
Version: 3
Subversion: 3
```

And then I changed numbers and still I get:

```
Version: 2
Saving number...
Subversion: 1
Saving number...
Read numbers:
Version: 3
Subversion: 3
```

It should be:

```
Version: 2
Saving number...
Subversion: 1
Saving number...
Read numbers:
Version: 2
Subversion: 1
```

And I want to add that my target is to create a binary file where there are two uint16_t variables and then to seperatly read them from file. So I can write that Version: (first uint16_t), Subversion: (second uint16_t)

Comment: The program you show, what's wrong with it? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected behavior? Unexpected output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And edit your question to include all the details I asked for, and also the expected and actual output.

Comment: every time you call reading int, it starts at the beginning of the file

Comment: For reading you should open the file once, read everything you need, and then close it once. Similarly, for writing you should open the file once, write everything you need to (from the beginning, without the `ios:app` flag) and close it. If you really want one function to read one `uint16_t` then just pass it a reference to the already open ofstream as a parameter.

Comment: File offset is not measured in bits.

Comment: Note that your `reading_uint16_t` calls can occur in any order, which is another good reason to not use global mutable state.

Comment: @Garrett Gutierrez if i delete _ios::app_, it won't add text but overwrite what is already in a file. I don't understand how to pass a reference to ofstream

Comment: @PalKol ofstreams keep track of where your last write was. So if you open a file, do 2 writes, and then close the file the second write will be immediately after the first write. If there was data already in the file when you opened it without the `ios::app` flag then the data that was already there will be overwritten. Otherwise the file will get larger and larger with each execution of the program until you delete the file or open it without the `ios::app` flag. I assume you want the file to just have 2 numbers in it at all times.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez when I deleted it I have only last number written. For example: Version: 2
Saving number...
Subversion: 1
Saving number...
Read numbers:
Version: 1
Subversion: 1

Answer (score 0):

So your understanding would probably be improved by looking at a function that extracted all the `uint16_t`s in numbers.bin. Presuming all that numbers.bin contains is `uint16_t`s then you could do something like this:

```
ifstream data("numbers.bin", ios_base::binary | ios_base::ate); // Starting at the end of the stream for sizing
const auto count = data.tellg() / sizeof(uint16_t); // tellg will report the number of characters in the file, sizeof(uint16_t) the numberof characters required to store a uint16_t, thus the division will give us the number of uint16_ts in numbers.bin
vector<uint16_t> numbers(count); // Allocate storage for all the uint16_ts in numbers.bin

data.seekg(0U, ios_base::beg); // Move the input position indicator to the beginning of the file for reading
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(numbers.data()), count * sizeof(uint16_t)); // Slurp the file into numbers
```

---

Similarly to access a specific element of numbers.bin we'll need to set the position accordingly:

```
ifstream data("numbers.bin", ios_base::binary); // Starting at the beginning of the file
const auto where = 2U; // This offset will be 0 based
uint16_t number; // Allocate storage for the element at where

data.seekg(where * sizeof(uint16_t)); // Move the input position indicator to the specified uint16_t
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number), sizeof(number)); // Read the element into number
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/385eed30d3b9f869)